Book about a coffee-seller and a young girl
I read this a year or so ago. I would guess that it was from the 1800s. It was definitely set in London.
The main character is a coffee-seller who is quite selfish. We are introduced to him selling his wares on the street. He sees a poor girl who is staring at his buns - and against his usual nature - he gives her one but tells her to not expect anymore.
At some point, he does a trick where he deliberately drops a coin. She quickly covers it with her foot. He feels vindicated and will certainly not let her have any more buns, but then she tearfully confesses. It becomes  more of a regular pattern, but he tells her not to follow him.
She follows him to his second place of work, which is a chapel where he works as a sideman preparing the cushions and candles for the rick ladies and gentlemen who come to hear the preacher speaks. The girl loves the chapel avoid being found, she hides behind a curtain when the gentlemen and ladies come in.
At this point, I lose the plot: The minister has two daughters, who see her and like her. The coffee-seller denies knowing her, not wanting to be revealed as a coffee seller. She soon stops coming and the coffee-seller feels guilty. He goes to her house and finds her sick, and alone in bed. He takes her away from her mother - who I think returns - to his house. That's the end of part one, I think.
In part two, it looks like the minister is so popular that they will have to move to a bigger premise. He plans to preach on a subject, but promises to the girl that he will preach on another subject, but then just before he begins to preach he has a stroke. We found out that this due to overworking. The minister never recovers as the great preacher that he was before.

Just to be sure, when you say "it was from the 1800s" do you mean the story was set in the 1800s, or that the book itself was from the 1800s?

@ClaraDíazSanchez hello, I think it was both written and set in the 1800s

"Jessica's First Prayer" by Hesba Stretton (pseudonym of Sarah Smith).
It can be read on gutenberg.org. Here's an excerpt with the coin scene:

Daniel sighed, and fidgeted about his crockery with a grave and
occupied air, as if he were pondering over the child’s notion of
goodness. He made good coffee, and the police left him alone! It was
quite true; yet still as he counted up the store of pence which had
accumulated in his strong canvas bag, he sighed again still more
heavily. He purposely let one of his pennies fall upon the muddy
pavement, and went on counting the rest busily, while he furtively
watched the little girl sitting at his feet. Without a shade of change
upon her small face she covered the penny with her foot and drew it in
carefully towards her, while she continued to chatter fluently to him.
For a moment a feeling of pain shot a pang through Daniel’s heart;
and then he congratulated himself on having entrapped the young thief.
It was time to be leaving now; but before he went he would make her
move her bare foot and disclose the penny concealed beneath it, and
then he would warn her never to venture near his stall again. This was
her gratitude, he thought; he had given her two breakfasts and more
kindness than he had shown to any fellow-creature for many a long
year, and at the first chance the young jade turned upon him and
robbed him! He was brooding over it painfully in his mind when
Jessica’s uplifted face changed suddenly, a dark flush crept over her
pale cheeks, and the tears started to her eyes. She stooped down, and
picking up the coin from among the mud she rubbed it bright and clean
upon her rags and laid it upon the stall close to his hand, but
without speaking a word. Daniel looked down upon her solemnly and
searchingly.
“What’s this?” he asked.
“Please, Mr. Dan’el,” she answered, “it dropped, and you didn’t hear
it.”
“Jess,” he said sternly, “tell me all about it.”
“Oh, please,” she sobbed, “I never had a penny of my own but once; and
it rolled close to my foot; and you didn’t see it; and I hid it up
sharp; and then I thought how kind you’d been, and how good the coffee
and buns are, and how you let me warm myself at your fire; and,
please, I couldn’t keep the penny any longer. You’ll never let me come
again, I guess.”


Thank you, there’s not a chance id’ve  found it again in my own
